# Gain is not constant in the inverting configuration of op amp (say LM 741)

Tags: operational-amplifier

If we have a gain of 10 for inverting configuration of an op amp and we increase the amplitude of the input signal, why is the output of my circuit not continuously producing 10 times amplification?

Comment: If you want a useful answer please provide a schematic, the nature of your input signal (e.g. waveshape, frequency, amplitude), and your method of measuring the output signal. With this information, we should be able to help you understand what you are observing.

Comment: Related: canonical question about the limitations of the 741 op amp: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp

Answer (score 1):

One possibly is slew rate limiting. Another is clipping as the outputs approach the supply rails. A third possibility is current limiting because your load is too heavy, either extra loading on the output or simply because the feedback resistor is too low in value.